# jQuery script takes me on top of page. How to modify this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to modify this code so that when I click on it, it will not take me to the top of the page?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".cont").click(function () {
            $("#feed").load('footer.php');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding `return false` or `e.preventDefault()`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".cont").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#feed").load('footer.php');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to listen to the event an prevent its default action.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cont").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#feed").load('footer.php');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shared with us won't take you to the top of the page.

You might have something like this in addition:

```
<a href="#" class="cont">
```

That takes you to the top of the page because that is where the URI `#` points.

Have [a more sensible URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Possibly:

```
<a href="footer.php" class="cont">
```

Then stop the default behaviour in the  script:

```
    $(".cont").click(function (e) {
        $("#feed").load(this.href);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cont").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#feed").load('footer.php');
    });
});
```

Or in `href` write something like `javascript:void(0);`